# How to update related records through a contact lookup for person accounts using process builder?

Tags: lookup, process-builder, contact, person-accounts

My situation:

- Process started from a Person Account
- I want to update all related custom object X records linked to this Person Account
- The link is made through a **Contact** lookup on object X
- Whether I select Account or Contact as the object to start the process from does not seem to matter (unlike for workflows on Person Accounts, which [only work if you start them from Account](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=account_person_behavior.htm))
- When I fire the process, nothing happens on the related records. However, the process does fire (other actions are executed correctly). I don't get any error messages

When I reproduce the exact same situation as above, but having the link made through an **Account** lookup on object X, the updates happen correctly. Again, it does not seem to matter if I select Account or Contact as the object to start the process from.

It looks like the process tries to do something like this to get the related records:

```
SELECT Id FROM ObjectX WHERE LookupField = AccountIdOfThePersonAccount
```

which will return no results since the lookup is filled with a ContactId in the first case.

**Is this indeed what is happening? Is it thus impossible to update those related records linked through a Contact lookup for Person Accounts with process builder?**

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing would make sense. Person Accounts add all of the contact fields to the Account Object that don't exist there (birth date, SSN, etc), duplicating those fields. A contact is not an Account. The relationships that you're looking for likely only exist between the Account and the other objects. The Contact will have a different relationship to them that's seen through the Account. You'll need to create a separate process if you want to reference Contact as opposed to the Account.

What I recommend is that you "hide" Contacts and only use Accounts. That's the whole idea behind having Person Accounts is to not need to use both. The Account object record should have everything you need from the Contact object record already on it.